# Resend the request page

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I am trying to resend the page that has make the request.

I have tried with so many forms, but no one works.

Can some one help me.

That works like that:

You are on a page and you click a link, this link send some information to my controller who validate that, but when this arrive to the controller, this validate that. If is valid all works ok, but if is invalid I need reload the page with a message.

Please help. Some of the things that i had tried are.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($request->get('_route'), $request->query->all()));
return $response->getContext()->getController()->redirect($request->getUri());
return $this->container->get('request')->getPathInfo();
```

etc.

Please I need help with that.

Comment: If it is not valid you want to redirect to another page and keep all the submitted data and if is valid keep the link process going, right? It will help if you provide your controller action, too

Comment: No, if it is not valid I want reload the page that make the request.

Comment: and keep all the passed params in query string?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Forward` instead

```
return $this->forward($request->get('_route'), array(), $request->query->all());
```

If your path has any parameters instead of the empty array use those parameters in an associative array.

[Symfony Forward Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) 
[Symfony Forward API](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_forward)